# cardview recyclerview android

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, cardview

Здравствуйте! Я новичок в Android не могу понять как пользоваться `cardview` и `recyclerview`. помогите пожалуйста. был на разных сайтах, но до сих пор до меня не доходит. У меня есть вот этот код cardview.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#172131">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/rest1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="-47dp"
            android:background="#64212C3E"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="Название"
            android:textColor="#dcffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_text2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="Описание бла бла бла бла бла бла"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, как связать этот cardview c recyclerview

Comment: Опишите подробнее что именно вам не понятно. Иначе чем вам помочь кроме давания ссылок на статьи которые вы не поняли?

Comment: В статьях что я читал, показывают как добавлять cardview, но не объясняют что с ним дальше делать, либо дают уже законченый код, но там я как бы также ничего не понимаю

Comment: Не очень понятно чего вы ждёте от нас, какой помощи. Мы можем написать аналог статей, которые вас непонятны - но зачем? Их написаны сотни уже и они вам не понятны.К тому же такие статьи не совсем по формату сайта. Вот если бы вы привели какой-то конкретный пример кода, который вам не понятен - тогда другое дело - будет хотя бы понятно что отвечать.

Comment: Вероятно, сложность заключается с пониманием работы адаптера и подключением библиотек, которые в уроках задействованы.

Comment: Я сделал все как здесь https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html?hl=ru   написал код cardview и recycler view, и теперь хочу понять как их связать. еще хочу понять как сделать так чтобы появлялись новые карточки